# simple-cdd suddenly stopped working

Tags: debian

I'm using `simple-cdd` package to build a custom Debian image, and everything worked fine. However today (May 8 2019) when I tried to use it again, it always gave me:

```
$ build-simple-cdd --conf cdd.conf
key 6FB2A1C265FFB764:
3 signatures not checked due to missing keys
key 8B48AD6246925553:
6 signatures not checked due to missing keys
key CBF8D6FD518E17E1:
2 signatures not checked due to missing keys
key 7638D0442B90D010:
3 signatures not checked due to missing keys
key 9D6D8F6BC857C906:
3 signatures not checked due to missing keys
key EF0F382A1A7B6500:
2 signatures not checked due to missing keys
key E0B11894F66AEC98:
3 signatures not checked due to missing keys
key EDA0D2388AE22BA9:
3 signatures not checked due to missing keys
2019-05-08 16:14:03 ERROR reprepro: updating package lists exited with code 255
2019-05-08 16:14:03 ERROR Last 3 lines of standard error:
2019-05-08 16:14:03 ERROR reprepro: updating package lists: VerifyRelease condition '6FB2A1C265FFB764|8B48AD6246925553|CBF8D6FD518E17E1|7638D0442B90D010|9D6D8F6BC857C906|EF0F382A1A7B6500|E0B11894F66AEC98|04EE7237B7D453EC|EDA0D2388AE22BA9|AA8E81B4331F7F50' lists expired key '6FB2A1C265FFB764'.
2019-05-08 16:14:03 ERROR reprepro: updating package lists: (To use it anyway, append it with a '!' to force usage).
2019-05-08 16:14:03 ERROR reprepro: updating package lists: There have been errors!
2019-05-08 16:14:03 ERROR reprepro failed with exit code: 255
```

I tried to install `simple-cdd` on another machine (both use Debian 9), but it still gave me the same error. Is this a problem with the package, and where is the full log of `reprepro` stored?

Comment: I've the same error, started at the same time. So it seems to be a global thing

Comment: https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1679451.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is due to the key 6FB2A1C265FFB764 that expired on 2019-05-07.

The keyring that is used by simple-cdd is /usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-keyring.gpg. The solution is to copy the keyring, remove the expired key from the new copy and then tell simple-cdd to use the new keyring.

For example:

List the keys in the Debian keyring:

```
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring=/usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-keyring.gpg --list-keys
```

This lists:

```
/usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-keyring.gpg
----------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2012-05-08 [SC] [expired: 2019-05-07]
      ED6D65271AACF0FF15D123036FB2A1C265FFB764
uid           [ expired] Wheezy Stable Release Key <debian-release@lists.debian.org>

pub   rsa4096 2012-04-27 [SC] [expires: 2020-04-25]
      A1BD8E9D78F7FE5C3E65D8AF8B48AD6246925553
uid           [ unknown] Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (7.0/wheezy) <ftpmaster@debian.org>

pub   rsa4096 2013-08-17 [SC] [expires: 2021-08-15]
      75DDC3C4A499F1A18CB5F3C8CBF8D6FD518E17E1
uid           [ unknown] Jessie Stable Release Key <debian-release@lists.debian.org>

pub   rsa4096 2014-11-21 [SC] [expires: 2022-11-19]
      126C0D24BD8A2942CC7DF8AC7638D0442B90D010
uid           [ unknown] Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (8/jessie) <ftpmaster@debian.org>

pub   rsa4096 2014-11-21 [SC] [expires: 2022-11-19]
      D21169141CECD440F2EB8DDA9D6D8F6BC857C906
uid           [ unknown] Debian Security Archive Automatic Signing Key (8/jessie) <ftpmaster@debian.org>

pub   rsa4096 2017-05-20 [SC] [expires: 2025-05-18]
      067E3C456BAE240ACEE88F6FEF0F382A1A7B6500
uid           [ unknown] Debian Stable Release Key (9/stretch) <debian-release@lists.debian.org>

pub   rsa4096 2017-05-22 [SC] [expires: 2025-05-20]
      E1CF20DDFFE4B89E802658F1E0B11894F66AEC98
uid           [ unknown] Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (9/stretch) <ftpmaster@debian.org>
sub   rsa4096 2017-05-22 [S] [expires: 2025-05-20]

pub   rsa4096 2017-05-22 [SC] [expires: 2025-05-20]
      6ED6F5CB5FA6FB2F460AE88EEDA0D2388AE22BA9
uid           [ unknown] Debian Security Archive Automatic Signing Key (9/stretch) <ftpmaster@debian.org>
sub   rsa4096 2017-05-22 [S] [expires: 2025-05-20]
```

Copy the keyring:

```
cp -a /usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-keyring.gpg /home/clean-disk/new-debian-archive-keyring.gpg
```

Delete the expired key from the new keyring:

```
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring=/home/clean-disk/new-debian-archive-keyring.gpg --delete-key "6FB2A1C265FFB764" --yes
```

Tell simple-cdd to use the new keyring:

```
cp -a /usr/share/simple-cdd/profiles /home/clean-disk
cd /home/clean-disk

simple-cdd --conf profiles/test.conf --profiles test --keyring /home/clean-disk/new-debian-archive-keyring.gpg
```